# Is there any way to draw a canvas inbetween the video and the contols using HTML <video>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

I create a canvas over the video frames playing in the HTML . But the canvas would also cover the controls. I would like to place the canvas in between the frame and the controls. Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: If you are using custom controls (with HTML that is outside of the `<video>` element), yes, otherwise, no (the controls are part of the video element). But if you don't need to listen for mouse events on the canvas (mouse moves, clicks...), you can simply place it in front of the video player, and add this to your css `canvas { pointer-events: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the canvas to respond to click or other such events, as @blex has explained in a comment you can set `pointer-events: none` on the canvas.

However, if you need such events and  you are not providing your own video controls, one crude but practical way is to have the canvas overlay most of the video but leave the bottom free for the built-in controls. For example:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1vmin;
  border-color: red; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999999;  
}
.changecolor {
  border-color: blue; /* just to show that the canvas has been clicked */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <video class="video" src="https://rgspaces.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/christmas-card-2020.mp4" controls ></video>
   <canvas class="canvas" onclick="this.classList.toggle('changecolor');"></canvas>
</div>
```